# Issue with creating custom loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to fine-tune GPT2 text summary and my training example look like this:

`Text: {text}\nSummary: {summary}`

So I wanted to create a custom loss function that only cares tokens coming after word 'Summary'

Here is my current code

**Custom loss funcion**

```
def custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False, summary_token_id=None):
    scc = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=from_logits)
    mask = tf.math.cumsum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, summary_token_id), dtype=tf.float32), axis=-1)
    sample_weight = tf.cast(mask > 0, dtype=tf.float32)  # This sets weight to 0 for all tokens before 'Summary' token
    return scc(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

**Compiling the model and training**

```
preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.from_preset(
    "gpt2_base_en",
    sequence_length=128,
)
gpt2_lm = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLM.from_preset(
    "gpt2_base_en", preprocessor=preprocessor
)

num_epochs = 1

# Linearly decaying learning rate.
learning_rate = keras.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(
    5e-5,
    decay_steps=train_ds.cardinality() * num_epochs,
    end_learning_rate=0.0,
)

gpt2_lm.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate),
    loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: custom_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=True, summary_token_id=summary_token_id),
    weighted_metrics=["accuracy"],
)

gpt2_lm.fit(train_ds, epochs=num_epochs)
```

**But the training result is very strange. I got `loss: 0.0585 - accuracy: 0.5588` and accuracy moved very little during training.**

When I trained with just default loss function(`keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`) it worked pretty well getting loss of 1.3476 and accuracy of 0.6380 after one epoch.

Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong? Thanks